# How to Simplify this to the given answer? (matrix equation, trig functions)

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, matrices

Can someone help me to simplify 
$$\Bigg( \begin{matrix} 5\cos t &5\sin t \\2\cos t+\sin t & 2\sin t-\cos t\end{matrix}     \Bigg)
\Bigg(  \begin{matrix} u_1 \\u_2\end{matrix}      \Bigg)
=\Bigg( \begin{matrix}  -\cos t \\ \phantom{-} \sin t \end{matrix}    \Bigg)$$
to

$${u_1}={1\over5} \big(2-3\cos2t+\sin2t)$$
$$ u_2={1\over5} \big(-1-\cos2t-3\sin2t)?$$

Thank you.

Comment: this is a part of a problem,

Answer (score 3):

$$AX=B$$
$$X=A^{-1}B$$

Where $X$ is the variable/unknown vector, $A$ is the coefficient matrix, and $B$ is the solution vector.

See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_of_linear_equations#Matrix_solution

Comment: This is a start, but if you need more direction, let me know--I'm always glad to help! :)

Comment: I want to use simplify rows Not inverse.

Comment: Ugh.  I've got a class to head to--let me think about that for a bit.

Comment: That seem to be the solution to me, you still need to apply some trigonometric identities in the intermediate steps

Comment: You could try the effect of multiplying the first row by $\cos t$ and the second row by $2 \cos t - \sin t$ - but whichever way you do it, it is essentially the same problem, and the determinant of the matrix you have comes out as an easy number - so the inverse can be written down. Why use more steps than you need to solve the problem?